# TensorFlow:'Tensor' object has no attribute 'initializer', occurs after several turns when reading dataset

Tags: tensorflow

I'm using TensorFlow to train a CNN. It works fine at the beginning to read one or two datasets and train but suddenly goes wrong when start to read the third.

It says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 249, in <module>
    train()
  File "train.py", line 195, in train
    X, L = input_data1.train_data(filename)
  File "/home/lily/Documents/MOT_train/input_data1.py", line 128, in train_data
    neg_couple_list,neg_lab = get_neg_couple(fileroot) #read examples
  File "/home/lily/Documents/MOT_train/input_data1.py", line 57, in get_neg_couple
    local_init = tf.local_variables_initializer()
  File "/home/lily/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 1184, in local_variables_initializer
    return variables_initializer(local_variables())
  File "/home/lily/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 1149, in variables_initializer
    return control_flow_ops.group(*[v.initializer for v in var_list], name=name)
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'initializer'
```

*input_data1* is the py script wrote for reading datasets.I use global and local initializer:

```
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()  
local_init = tf.local_variables_initializer()
```

The version of TensorFlow is 1.1.0.

I don't understand why the problem occurs after several turns and what caused it.

Could anyone help? I would really appreciate that.

Here are my codes

*train.py* for training:

```
import  tensorflow as tf  
import input_data1
import numpy as np
import os

trainroot = './train_tfrecord/train/' 
testroot = './train_tfrecord/test/' 

class network(object):  
    def __init__(self):  
        with tf.variable_scope("weights"):  
            self.weights={  
                'conv1':tf.get_variable('conv1',[4,4,6,20],initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer_conv2d()),  
                'conv2':tf.get_variable('conv2',[3,3,20,40],initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer_conv2d()),  
                'conv3':tf.get_variable('conv3',[3,3,40,60],initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer_conv2d()),   
                'fc1':tf.get_variable('fc1',[4*4*60,60],initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),  
                'fc2':tf.get_variable('fc2',[60,2],initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),  
                }  
        with tf.variable_scope("biases"):  
            self.biases={  
                'conv1':tf.get_variable('conv1',[20,],initializer=tf.constant_initializer(value=0.0, dtype=tf.float32)),  
                'conv2':tf.get_variable('conv2',[40,],initializer=tf.constant_initializer(value=0.0, dtype=tf.float32)),  
                'conv3':tf.get_variable('conv3',[60,],initializer=tf.constant_initializer(value=0.0, dtype=tf.float32)),  
                'fc1':tf.get_variable('fc1',[60,],initializer=tf.constant_initializer(value=0.0, dtype=tf.float32)),  
                'fc2':tf.get_variable('fc2',[2,],initializer=tf.constant_initializer(value=0.0, dtype=tf.float32))  

            }  
    def inference(self,images):  
        images = tf.reshape(images, shape=[-1, 32,32, 6])# [batch, in_height, in_width, in_channels]  
        images=(tf.cast(images,tf.float32)/255.-0.5)*2  

        # 1st layer  
        conv1=tf.nn.bias_add(tf.nn.conv2d(images, self.weights['conv1'], strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME'),  
                         self.biases['conv1'])  

        relu1= tf.nn.relu(conv1)  
        pool1=tf.nn.max_pool(relu1, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='VALID')  


        # 2nd layer  
        conv2=tf.nn.bias_add(tf.nn.conv2d(pool1, self.weights['conv2'], strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME'),  
                         self.biases['conv2'])  
        relu2= tf.nn.relu(conv2)  
        pool2=tf.nn.max_pool(relu2, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='VALID')  


        # 3rd layer
        conv3=tf.nn.bias_add(tf.nn.conv2d(pool2, self.weights['conv3'], strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME'),  
                         self.biases['conv3'])  
        relu3= tf.nn.relu(conv3)  
        pool3=tf.nn.max_pool(relu3, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='VALID')  


        # Fully connected layer  
        flatten = tf.reshape(pool3, [-1, self.weights['fc1'].get_shape().as_list()[0]])    
        drop1=tf.nn.dropout(flatten,0.5)  
        fc1=tf.matmul(drop1, self.weights['fc1'])+self.biases['fc1']    
        fc_relu1=tf.nn.relu(fc1)    
        fc2=tf.matmul(fc_relu1, self.weights['fc2'])+self.biases['fc2']  

        return  fc2  

    def sorfmax_loss(self,predicts,labels):  
        predicts=tf.nn.softmax(predicts) 
        loss =-tf.reduce_mean(labels * tf.log(predicts))
        self.cost= loss  
        return self.cost  

    def inference_test(self,images):           
        images = tf.reshape(images, shape=[-1, 32,32, 6])# [batch, in_height, in_width, in_channels]  
        images=(tf.cast(images,tf.float32)/255.-0.5)*2#归一化处理  

        # 1st layer  
        conv1=tf.nn.bias_add(tf.nn.conv2d(images, self.weights['conv1'], strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME'),  
                         self.biases['conv1'])  

        relu1= tf.nn.relu(conv1)  
        pool1=tf.nn.max_pool(relu1, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='VALID')  


        # 2nd layer  
        conv2=tf.nn.bias_add(tf.nn.conv2d(pool1, self.weights['conv2'], strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME'),  
                         self.biases['conv2'])  
        relu2= tf.nn.relu(conv2)  
        pool2=tf.nn.max_pool(relu2, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='VALID')  


        # 3rd layer  
        conv3=tf.nn.bias_add(tf.nn.conv2d(pool2, self.weights['conv3'], strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME'),  
                         self.biases['conv3'])  
        relu3= tf.nn.relu(conv3)  
        pool3=tf.nn.max_pool(relu3, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='VALID')  


        # Fully connected layer  
        flatten = tf.reshape(pool3, [-1, self.weights['fc1'].get_shape().as_list()[0]])  

        fc1=tf.matmul(flatten, self.weights['fc1'])+self.biases['fc1']    
        fc_relu1=tf.nn.relu(fc1)    
        fc2=tf.matmul(fc_relu1, self.weights['fc2'])+self.biases['fc2']  

        return  fc2  
    def optimer(self,loss,lr):  
            train_optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(lr).minimize(loss)  

            return train_optimizer


def train():

    trX = tf.placeholder("uint8", [None, 32, 32, 6], name='trX')
    trY = tf.placeholder("float32",[None,2], name='trY')
    teX = tf.placeholder("uint8", [None, 32, 32, 6], name='teX')
    teY = tf.placeholder("float32",[None,2], name='teY')


    global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)
    add_global = global_step.assign_add(1)

    initial_learning_rate = 0.01   
    learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(initial_learning_rate,
                                           global_step=global_step,
                                           decay_steps=100,decay_rate=0.9)

    net = network()    
    inf=net.inference(trX)  
    loss=net.sorfmax_loss(inf,trY)  
    opti=net.optimer(loss,learning_rate)  


    test_inf=net.inference_test(teX)  
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.cast(tf.argmax(test_inf,1),tf.float32), tf.cast(tf.argmax(teY,1),tf.float32))  
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))


    init_all = tf.global_variables_initializer()      
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    tf.add_to_collection('test_inf',test_inf)

    batchsize = 100


    testX = []
    testL = []
    testname = os.listdir(testroot)
    for record in testname:
        filename = testroot+record + '/'
        print '============reading testset %s =============' % record
        X1,L1 = input_data1.train_data(filename)
        if len(testX)==0:
            testX=X1
            testL=L1
        else:
            testX = np.concatenate((testX,X1), axis = 0)
            testL = np.concatenate((testL,L1), axis = 0)
    index = np.random.permutation(len(testX))  
    Xte = testX[index,:,:,:]
    Yte = testL[index,:]
    print 'total number of testset', len(Xte)

    setnames = os.listdir(trainroot)
    for record in setnames:
        filename = trainroot+record + '/'
        print '============reading trainset %s =============' % record

        for k in range(1):
            X, L = input_data1.train_data(filename)
            print 'total example couple number', len(X)

            index = np.random.permutation(len(X))  
            Xtr = X[index,:,:,:]
            Ytr = L[index,:]

            print 'trainset number ', len(Xtr)

            with tf.Session() as session:  
                session.run(init_all) 
                ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state("./save") 
                if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path: 

                    new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('save/model.meta')
                    new_saver.restore(session, "save/model")  
                    print "Model restored"
                itertimes = int(float(len(Xtr))/batchsize) #divide training data by batchsize

                for iter in range(itertimes):  
                    start = iter*batchsize
                    if iter>=len(Xtr)/batchsize:               
                        end = len(Xtr)
                    else:
                        end = (iter+1)*batchsize

                    loss_np,_,inf_np,_ =session.run([loss,opti,inf,add_global], feed_dict={trX: Xtr[start:end], trY:Ytr[start:end]})  

                    if (iter+1)%10==0: 
                        rate=session.run(learning_rate)
                        print '*****train loss: %s , learning rate: %s *****' % (loss_np,rate)  
                        if (iter+1)%50==0:
                            accuracy_np=session.run(accuracy, feed_dict={teX: Xte, teY:Yte})  
                            print '~~~~~test accuracy %s ~~~~~' % accuracy_np

                print 'done'
                saver.save(session, "save/model")

                print "Model saved"

    print '-------------------------------------------------------------'
    print '----------------------train done-----------------------------'      
    print '-------------------------------------------------------------'

train()
```

*input_data1.py* for reading the data:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os
import sys
import numpy as np
import random

setroot = 'ETH-Bahnhof'
root = './train_tfrecord/testfake/'  #root of TFRecords


#Read tfrecords
def decode_from_tfrecords(filename_queue):    
    reader=tf.TFRecordReader()
    _,serialized=reader.read(filename_queue)  
    features=tf.parse_single_example(serialized,features={ 'frame': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
                                                   'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
                                       'img_raw' : tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)})
    frame = tf.cast(features["frame"], tf.int64)   
    label=features['label']
    img = tf.decode_raw(features["img_raw"], tf.uint8)
    img = tf.reshape(img, [32, 32, 3])    

    p = random.uniform(0,1)
    if p<0.3:
        img = tf.image.random_flip_up_down(img)
    elif (p>0.3) and (p<0.7):
        img = tf.random_crop(img, [32, 24, 3])
        img = tf.image.resize_images(img, (32, 32), method=0)  

    return img,label,frame

def get_neg_couple(fileroot, times):  #Read negative examples(different objects)
    filenames = os.listdir(fileroot)  
    Filequeue = [] 
    for f in filenames:
        fq = fileroot + f
        Filequeue.append(fq)
    neg_list = []  
    f_queue1 = tf.train.string_input_producer(Filequeue,num_epochs=1)   #put the file in to a queue
    Img1,Lab1,Frm1 = decode_from_tfrecords(f_queue1)
    batch_img1,batch_lab1, batch_frm1 = tf.train.shuffle_batch([Img1,Lab1,Frm1], batch_size=1, 
                                    capacity=15, min_after_dequeue=13, num_threads=1)   

    f_queue2 = tf.train.string_input_producer(Filequeue,num_epochs=1)   #put the file in to a queue
    Img2,Lab2,Frm2 = decode_from_tfrecords(f_queue2)
    batch_img2,batch_lab2,batch_frm2 = tf.train.shuffle_batch([Img2,Lab2,Frm2], batch_size=1, 
                                    capacity=15, min_after_dequeue=13, num_threads=1) 
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()  
    local_init = tf.local_variables_initializer()
    for i in range(times):
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            sess.run(init)
            sess.run(local_init)            
            coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
            threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord,sess=sess)
            try:
                while not coord.should_stop():
                    img1,lab1,frm1 = sess.run([batch_img1,batch_lab1,batch_frm1])
                    img2,lab2,frm2 = sess.run([batch_img2,batch_lab2,batch_frm2])
                    if lab1!=lab2:                    
                        couple = np.concatenate((img1,img2), axis = 3)
                        if len(neg_list)==0:
                            neg_list=couple
                        else:
                            neg_list = np.concatenate((neg_list,couple), axis = 0)


            except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:            
                coord.request_stop()
            finally:
                coord.request_stop()
                coord.join(threads)

    print '***************Negative couple read done, number %d*****************' % len(neg_list)
    return neg_list

def get_pos_couple(fileroot, times):  #Read positive examples (same objects)
    filenames = os.listdir(fileroot)  
    Filequeue = [] 
    for f in filenames:
        fq = fileroot + f
        Filequeue.append(fq)
    pos_list = []  

    f_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(Filequeue,num_epochs=1)   #put the file in to a queue
    Img,Lab,Frm = decode_from_tfrecords(f_queue)
    batch_img,batch_lab, batch_frm = tf.train.shuffle_batch([Img,Lab,Frm], batch_size=2, 
                                    capacity=15, min_after_dequeue=13, num_threads=1)   

    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()  
    local_init = tf.local_variables_initializer()
    for i in range(times):
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            sess.run(init)
            sess.run(local_init)
            coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
            threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord,sess=sess)
            try:
                while not coord.should_stop():
                    img,lab,frm = sess.run([batch_img,batch_lab,batch_frm])
                    if lab[0]==lab[1]:
                        couple = img.reshape(1,img.shape[1],img.shape[2],6)

                        if len(pos_list)==0:
                            pos_list=couple
                        else:
                            pos_list =  np.concatenate((pos_list,couple), axis = 0)

            except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:               
                coord.request_stop()
            finally:
                coord.request_stop()
                coord.join(threads)

    print '***************Positive couple read done, number %d*****************' % len(pos_list)
    return pos_list#,lab_list

def train_data(fileroot):    
    neg_couple_list = get_neg_couple(fileroot,5) #read examples
    pos_couple_list = get_pos_couple(fileroot,5) 

    Xneg = np.random.permutation(neg_couple_list)  #shaffle the ordered examples
    Yneg = [0]*len(Xneg)
    Xpos = np.random.permutation(pos_couple_list)  
    Ypos = [1]*len(Xpos)

    X = np.vstack((Xneg,Xpos))  #congeal pos and neg examples as a whole list
    y = Yneg + Ypos
    Y = tf.one_hot(y,2)
    Lab = tf.cast(Y, tf.float32)
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        L = sess.run(Lab)
    return X,L
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/9674

> When export/input meta graph, user expect all collections been
>   rebuilded on target graph, but it turns out local variables on target
>   collection is not Variable but Tensor because local variable do not
>   have it's proto fn registered

refer to https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9747 for some kind of work around

Actually, add the following piece of code solve my problem. You can have a try.

```
from tensorflow.core.framework import variable_pb2
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
from tensorflow.python.ops import variables
from tensorflow.python.framework.ops import register_proto_function

register_proto_function(
    ops.GraphKeys.LOCAL_VARIABLES,
    proto_type=variable_pb2.VariableDef,
    to_proto=variables.Variable.to_proto,
    from_proto=variables.Variable.from_proto)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it seems the same problem indeed. But There seems no certain solution yet. Do you have any idea what I should do?

Comment: maybe you shall post your code to make the problem explicit.

Comment: But I have another problem. I trained the CNN to predict the similarity between two detections of pedestrians so it can be used in multi-object tracking. When I use a video sequence as test set to calculate the accuracy, the outcome seems fine, about 0.9. But when I apply the network to make prediction on two detections of same object I extracted from that test sequence, it performs badly. The data are in same form. And the predictions made on detections of different objects, work better.I can't think of why the prediction performances are not consistent. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: How do you calculate the accuracy when you use the trained cnn to predict the similarity between two detections of pedestrians?

Comment: btw, since my answer works, please accept my answer. If you have other problems, you're welcomed to send an email to jiqiujia@foxmail.com.