# Tensorflow: Registering two proto functions with name 'local_variables' error

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to import a metagraph in tensorflow and when I want to initialize my weights variable:

```
W = tf.get_collection('W')[0]
session.run([W.initializer])
```

I get the error:

```
'Tensor' object has no attribute 'initializer'"
```

I found here ([TensorFlow:'Tensor' object has no attribute 'initializer', occurs after several turns when reading dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45402822/tensorflowtensor-object-has-no-attribute-initializer-occurs-after-several)) that this problem is related to the fact that "local variables on target collection is not Variable but Tensor because local variable do not have it's proto fn registered". They propose to add this code to the model core:

```
from tensorflow.core.framework import variable_pb2
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
from tensorflow.python.ops import variables
from tensorflow.python.framework.ops import register_proto_function

register_proto_function(
  ops.GraphKeys.LOCAL_VARIABLES,
  proto_type=variable_pb2.VariableDef,
  to_proto=variables.Variable.to_proto,
  from_proto=variables.Variable.from_proto)
```

So I added the above code in my add_final_training_ops function but now get the following error:

```
KeyError: "Registering two proto functions with name 'local_variables' !(Previous registration was in _find_and_load_unlocked <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:950)"
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Which TF version are you using?

Comment: @MPękalski, I have the same issue, and am on Python 3.6 and TF 1.12.0; (attempting to run ludwig 0.1.0)

Comment: Without a minimal end-to-end example I think it will be hard to help. You may want to reopen the ticket https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9747

Comment: They mention that this issue has been fixed on TF 1.4.1 https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9747

Comment: Minimal end-to-end: Windows 10, CUDA 9.2 with relevant cuDNN; conda create test_env python=3.6; activate that environment; then pip install ludwig (gathering all reqs). then pip uninstall tensorflow; then pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.12.0; then jupyter notebook; then in the notebook, try "from ludwig import LudwigModel" ... fails with the above.